# Обновление консольного сообщения || JS

Tags: javascript, консоль

Можно ли как-то обновить/перезаписать консольное сообщение?

К примеру, я вывел сообщение:

```
console.log("Hello,");
```

Через секунду `console.log(User.getID());`
Потом `console.log(" world!");`
А потом дату `console.log(dayjs().unix().toString());`

И как мне группировать 1 и 3 сообщение, даже если они вызываются в разное время?

Т.е. должно получиться примерно так:

```
Hello, world!
UserID: 1123
Unix Timestamp: 123123123
```

Объясню, зачем мне это. У меня подключен сокет, и сообщения с него хотелось бы получать в консоль, чтобы не заходить во вкладку network и не искать там. Но события приходят в разное время и появляются между другими сообщениями. Хотелось как-то группировать все эти сообщения в одном месте и просто обновлять его. Такое вообще можно реализовать?

Comment: Если другие сообщения не нужны, то можете очищать консоль через `console.clear()`

Comment: @EzioMercer, я думал об этом, но мне все же нужно видеть другие сообщения, ибо там могут как параметры отладки быть, так и ошибки.

Comment: А нужные вам сообщения идут всегда в одном и том же порядке?

Comment: Нет. Сообщение сокета может придти в любой момент, поэтому часто появляется между другими сообщениями.

Comment: Тогда можно просто формировать пустой объект `{}`, и при каждом нужном сообщении добавлять его в объект и потом проверять есть ли все нужные поля? Если да, то печатать его, если нет, то ничего не делать

Comment: И для красоты, можно будет напечатать через `console.table` :)